# Looking for an interactive decision tree

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I'm looking for an interactive decision tree for a web site powered by Wordpress.
I want an actual look of a decision tree. At the beginning I want only the root visible and with each decision that the user makes to display the next level of the tree.
I've been looking for quite a while now, the closest I found was: http://listui.com/?p=84
which was also referred here. But this doesn't give the sense of a tree.
I prefer jQuery code but FLASH is also acceptable.
Or as an alternative, please direct me to a jQuery tutorial for building a tree diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://philau.willbowman.com/2012/digitalInnovation/DevelopmentReferences/LIBS/d3JS/examples/tree/tree-interactive.html

This example comes from Mike Bostocks Data Driven Documents. His source:
http://d3js.org/

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a dead link/domain -- any updated example(s) you might be able to provide?

Comment: @jimiayler: You can simply paste the link in the Wayback Machine of archive.org to access a cached version which is working: https://web.archive.org/web/20161215215807/http://philau.willbowman.com/2012/digitalInnovation/DevelopmentReferences/LIBS/d3JS/examples/tree/tree-interactive.html